# Flash CreateJS navigate to URL on enter last frame

Tags: createjs

I have an anim created in Flash CS6 and exported using CreateJS framework. The only thing I need is for the animation to redirect the browser to another URL when the anim completes.

In AS3 this does what I need just fine:

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://mywebsite.com/choose.php"), "_self");
```

For the CreateJS version I have tried this with no luck (maybe my function name is wrong?):

```
/* JS
this.onEnterFrame = function() {
    window.location = "http://mywebsite.com/choose.php";
}
*/
```

Also, have do I get the CreateJS version to open the new URL in `_self` window (same domain).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this.onEnterFrame = function(){ } and change window to document. It should look like the following:

```
/* js
this.stop();
document.location = "http://www.google.com";
*/
```